# Xubuntu 18.04 не выключается

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu, xfce

Поставил xubuntu 18.04. При нажатии shutdown пк не выключается, просто бесконечно долго грузится анимация и все. С чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?

Comment: наверно на оф сайте точно скажут ...или на ubuntuforum я туда писал когда были проблемы у меня

Comment: Это вопрос для техсаппорта, а не для SO.

Comment: Пользуюсь той же версией xubuntu с момента её релиза и ничего подобного не испытывал. Попробуйте установить другую версию видео-драйвера.

Comment: А что за анимация грузится? В иксах или где?

Comment: Если нажать на `Esc` - чё будет показывать?